# google Sheet Change date on specific range change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have some trouble, in my sheet i have specific range name Comm 1 and so one. I want to check if someone have modified them and if its yes have another range to change the date to the day they was modified.

Ex :

Range Comm 1 was modified so i want a cell or the range Change 1 to be the date of the modification and so on.

if its Comm 2 then Change 2 use the date of today.

I have tried to use the today function and the On edit function :

```
function myFunction(reference) {
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(reference);
var firstColumn = range.getColumn()
}
```

Comment: Could you share more about how you used the simple trigger function `onEdit(eventObject)`? I would absolutely expect that approach to work. Consider reviewing the event object formats on the Apps Script documentation site - it provides information about what was modified.

Comment: Now i didnt event use de trigger i didnt know on how to use it on this fonction. So far i can implement the date on the right cell if i have the cell activate  var cell = sheet.getRange('C1'); 
  var cellbase = sheet.getRange('A1');
  var timezone = "GMT+2";
    var timestamp_format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format); 
  // cell.setValue(date);
  if( cellbase 
     = sheet.getActiveCell())
    cell.setValue(date); }

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit

Comment: I just tried it but everytime the function work on every cell :                                    `code    function onEdit(cellbase){                                                                         
var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                                                var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];                       var cell = sheet.getRange('C1'); var timezone = "GMT+2";
   var timestamp_format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format); 
   cell.setValue(date);
}`

Comment: of course, that is the point - functions with the "on edit" trigger run on every user edit. If you want to apply control flow logic, then you should do that. You can check, for example, the sheet name, the cell row, the cell column, the cell value, etc.

Comment: so i just have to Save the data in a var "S1" on the cell and after check on edit if the data changed ? and if yes i stamp the date in one cell then change the data  saved in the var S1.